# how to create tables using iText for .NET

Tags: c#, datatable, itext

I have 3 tables, I have created the first one an a normal way, but I can't create the other two tables in the position that I want,
Here's my code , in the first method I get the 3 tables one after the other and it's not what I want:

```
doc.Add(table1);
doc.Add(table2);
doc.Add(table3);
```

In the second try, the table 2 and 3 are not drawn when the table 1 is on more than 1 page (or maybe they are drawn in the first page but I can't see them),it's not good neither:

```
doc.Add(table1);
table2.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, doc.Left, doc.Top - 
table1.TotalHeight, writer.DirectContent);
table3.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, doc.Left + 205, doc.Top - 
table1.TotalHeight, writer.DirectContent);
```

This is what I want:

[image]

I appreciate all the help, thank you

Comment: Since you seem to be new at iText, please upgrade to [iText 7](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/NET). You are currently using a version of iText that is no longer supported. See [the tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-5-adding-abstractelement-objects-part-2) to learn more about tables in iText 7. In iText 7, there are `SetFixedPosition()` and `SetRelativePosition()` methods that allows you to add objects such as tables at a fixed or relative position.

Comment: I also edited your question to reflect that the name iTextSharp was abandoned in favor of the name iText for .NET more than two years ago. Please always check the official web site for the most recent information about a product. It's frustrating for the creators of iText when you don't, and it's frustrating for you to realize that you've wasted your time on an old version.

Comment: I can't change the version cuz it's not my project, whatever, I think i'll create new table with 2 columns and add table2 and 3 to it with addCell, Thank you for you interest

Comment: If it's an existing project, please be aware that a commercial license is required if the project is closed source. If you have a support contract with iText Software, you should use the closed ticketing system for questions like this. It's not allowed to use Stack Overflow for commercial support.